# how can read whole of page that variable address using php

Tags: php

how can Dynamic this code with php .my address is variable

```
<?php
$pagecontents = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
$html = htmlentities($pagecontents);
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: its really unclear, what you are asking, could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: hi. i have a program with c# that need to connect to php address and search the contents my address like  is http://aa.com/a or http://aa.com/b. this address is different address and my code just show a specific address like http://google.com .how can change code to include every address i want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I understood, what the goal is, but if you want to do the same thing, that you have shown in the question but with multiple sites, then you can do it with a simple loop:

```
$sites = ["aa.com/a", "aa.com/b"] // array(...) with earlier PHP versions
foreach($sites as $url) {
    $pagecontents = file_get_contents($url);
    echo htmlentities($pagecontents);
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, then please refactor the question, so it clearly explains, what you want to do!

Comment: this code is correct but how can access form c# .in c# i want to reach the content of url that is like http://asianwiki.com/Snow_Is_on_the_Sea    or   http://asianwiki.com/Birth_of_a_Beauty . but how can access to address in you code. i think i need to a function that reach the content like  http://aaa.com/do?Birth_of_a_Beauty or http://aaa.com/do?Snow_Is_on_the_Sea to  access content

Comment: like alexa.com like http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=google.com  in the end you just need to change the address like  http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=yahoo.com   .how can make php code to get the content of url with like above address

Comment: To get something from the url look at [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), and [sanitization](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php). But please update your question, because what you are asking now, seems like, its completely unrelated to what you originally wrote.